# Camera calibration algorithm evaluation

Tags: graphics, computer-vision, camera-calibration

Recently, I am developing algorithm to improvement the camera calibration algorithm in my research group. I would like to ask are there any method to evaluation the camera calibration algorithm so that  I can compare the result among difference algorithm?

The most easiest way I can think of is taking the mean square average of different between the calibrated one and the original one pixel-wise. Are there any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about *geometric camera calibration* (focal length, optical center, etc.), or *color calibration*?

For geometric camera calibration, the main criterion is reprojection errors. Presumably, you are using some sort of calibration pattern, like a checkerboard, where you can detect a set of points. To evaluate calibration  accuracy, you look at the distances between the detected points and the reprojected points.
This is what a calibration algorithm typically tries to minimize. Depending on the calibration software you use, you may also be able to look at the uncertainty of the estimated camera parameters.
See [this example in MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/evaluating-the-accuracy-of-single-camera-calibration.html).

Alternatively, you can use your calibrated camera to [measure an object of a known size](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/measuring-planar-objects-with-a-calibrated-camera.html), and see how precise your measurement is.

Comment: Are there any other ways?Because when I look though lots of camera caliration papers, there exists no standard way to characterize the effectiveness of algorithm, thus I would like to gather more method and choose some of them for my research.

Comment: Not really.  All calibration algorithms minimize reprojection errors, and their ultimate purpose is to measure things.

Comment: Ok. I see.  
In some other algorithms, they claim they would minimize the in parameter space or coordinate space, what do they mean?